# minimum collection of vertice disjoint path that covers a given vertice set

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, disjoint-sets, cyclic-graph

#### Problem

Given:

- A directed graph `G`
- A source vertex `s` in G and a target vertex `t` in G
- A set `S` of vertices of G

I want to find a collection of paths from `s` to `t` that covers `S`.

Then I want to partition the collection of paths into subcollections of vertex-disjoint paths.

Under these constraints, the objective is to minimise the number of subcollections.

#### Example

For instance, [C1 = {p1,p2,p3}, C2= {p4,p5}, C3= {p6,p7}] is a solution if:

- each p_i is a path from s to t
- p1,p2,p3 have no vertices in common except s and t;
- p4, p5 have no vertices in common except s and t;
- p6,p7 have no vertices in common except s and t;
- collectively, the 7 paths cover all vertices of S.

In that case, the number of subcollections is 3.

#### Question

What are some good algorithms or heuristics for this optimisation problem?

I already know min cost flow, and disjoint path algos, but they don't apply in my settings.

I tried min cost flow / node disjoint paths but one run only gives one collection at a time. I don't know how to adjust cost to cover the unexplored vertices.

Comment: Hello, I personally found the question unambiguous. I took the liberty of editing it to make it more clear. If I misrepresented your question @YufeiZheng, you can [rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75419067/revisions) my edit, or you can [edit] it further.

Comment: How many vertices do you have in your graph? Or alternatively, how many distinct paths are there from s to t? If it is small enough you can bruteforce it by enumerating all paths, then enumerating all maximal vertex-disjoint subsets of paths, then use these subsets to solve the subset cover problem.

Comment: graph is large.

Comment: @Stef Thanks for your editing. Your understanding of the problem is correct!  The graph is large.

Comment: @ravenspoint Some nice guy rephrased the question. Please review.

Comment: does anyone know how to give reward to good answers? I am willing to pay for good answers.

Comment: This is not the place for that.  If you want to pay someone to develop for you, hire someone. Perhaps through a bounty platform such as bountify or bountysource or similar.

Comment: @YufeiZheng Since no-one has posted anything better, I have implemented my algorithm.  Details in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given:
>
> A directed graph G
>
> A source vertex s in G and a target vertex t in G
>
> A set S of vertices of G
>
> I want to find a collection of paths from s to t that covers S.

- Use Dijkstra's algorithm to find a path from s to every vertex in S and from every point in S to t.
- Connect the paths to and from each S vertex into one path from s to t via a point in S.

You now have a collection of paths that, together, cover S.  Let's call it CS.

> Then I want to partition the collection of paths into subcollections
> of vertex-disjoint paths.

Note that if s, the source vertex, has an out degree of sOD, there can be no more than sOD paths in each vertex disjoint collection.

- Construct vVDP, an empty vector of vertex disjoint path collections
- LOOP P over paths in CS

  - SET found FALSE
  - LOOP cs over collections in vVDP

    - IF P is vertex disjoint with every path in cs

      - add P to cs
      - SET found TRUE
      - BREAK out of LOOP cs
  - IF found == false
    ADD collection containing P to vVDP

Here is a C++ implementation of this algorithm

```
void cProblem::collect()
{
    // loop over paths
    for (auto &P : vpath)
    {
        // loop over collections
        bool found = false;
        for (auto &cs : vVDP)
        {
            //loop over paths in collection
            bool disjoint;
            for (auto &csPath : cs)
            {
                // check that P is vertex disjoint with path in collection

                disjoint = true;
                for (auto vc : csPath)
                {
                    for (auto &vp : P)
                    {
                        if (vp == vc) {
                            disjoint = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if( ! disjoint )
                    break;
            }

            if (disjoint)
            {
                // P is vertex disjoint from every path in collection
                // add P to the collection

                cs.push_back(P);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            // P was NOT vertex disjoint with the paths in any collection
            // start a new collection with P

            std::vector<std::vector<int>> collection;
            collection.push_back(P);
            vVDP.push_back(collection);
        }
    }
}
```

The complete application is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so75419067

Detailed documentation id the required input file format at
https://github.com/JamesBremner/so75419067/wiki

If you post a real example in the correct format, I will run the algorithm on it for you.

Comment: Your algorithm works but does not try to minimize number of collections.
Moreover, it is not ture that "at least ( S vertex count / sOD ) collections" are needed. Consider the extreme case that S is all vertices in a graph like this:
s->a1->a2->a3->...->a100 -> t, s->b1->b2->b3->...->b100 -> t, s->c1->c2->c3->...->c100 -> t. Then one collection with 3 paths is sufficient to cover all nodes, not 300/3 =100 collection.

Comment: @YufeiZheng You are correct.  I have edited my note.